# Being a Pastamancer

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

So I made another account for the fun of trying another class, and thought I was doing good with the pastamancer until I had to go to the Cellar in the Typical Tavern. Those rats all one shot me, and I have no idea what I did wrong to lose so horribly to them (besides having low health).

Now I am grinding away in the Spooky Forest trying to get stronger. Any tips on how to be a Pastamancer or better places to grind for gear/levels?

Although I did just unlock the Hidden Temple.

Comment: I recommend sticking with moxie classes as a beginner just to get the hang of things. Spellcasters are immensely strong late game but they are very fragile, as you found out, early on, espeially if you have no permmed skills.

Comment: I'll build an answer when I get home, if noone gets that done before me.

Comment: @spartacus The only class I wouldn't suggest to beginners is Sauceror as the sauce spells have some strange synergy going on that is tough to juggle while trying to learn the rest of the game. Other classes are simple enough to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about Pastamancers is that, like most archetypal mages, they are squishy glass cannons. If you can get the jump on your enemies, you have a higher chance than the other classes of taking them out in one round. However, you are also more susceptible to *being* one-shot by monsters than the other classes, as Muscle classes can just tank hits while Moxie classes dodge them.

So, the important thing to do is have good Combat Initiative. If you're level 6, you can use the Springy Fusilli skill to gain +40% Combat Initiative, which is usually more than good enough. The Pastamancer's Epic weapon also gives bonus Combat Initiative, so try to grab that if you don't want to be so skill/buff reliant.

If you don't think you can one-shot your enemies, especially if you're taking on boss monsters, then you need to find the Pastamancer's best friend: Entangling Noodles. This skill easily gives the best bang for your buck. Learnable at level 2 and costing only 250 meat, Entangling Noodles is definitely one of your best spells. While it doesn't do any damage, it roots and prevents your enemies from attacking for several turns (the base is 3 for Pastamancers, I believe).

Comment: the hard part about so being spell intensive is generating enough meat early on to buy all those mystery juices.

Comment: Pastamancers don't have to resort to MMJ as they can eat pastas to recover MP.

Comment: that's true, he can always buy pasta I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

For caster classes, I usually attempt the following:

Equip +moxie equipment wherever possible, mp regen helps as well, but can also come from items, etc. between fights.

Use spells for damage, don't rely on basic attacks. You should be able to 1-2 shot most creatures.

Boost combat initiative where possible. Hitting first is very important for fragile caster-types.

Familiars can provide a variety of useful abilities, including damage, deleveling opponents, initiative boosts, health and mana regen, and preventing enemies from acting.

Don't be afraid to use items to grant yourself useful buffs, especially when adventuring in dangerous zones for your current abilities.

Comment: yah I eventually had to use two buffs to get 200% to my stats. was able to tear through the cellar pretty effectively.